# Combining JAX-WS and JAX-RS

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, jax-rs

I need to create a web service project that creates some web services and exposes the end points using SOAP and REST.  I've done a lot of JAX-RS work but I'm a little light on an JAX-WS implementations.  Is there an open sourced technology that implements both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/). It is an open source services framework which will allow you to do exactly what you need.

Comment: +1: I've done this and it's been a (mostly) smooth experience.

Comment: I also have used CXF (2.3.x) for a combined RS & WS service and had smooth sailing.